# How should I make the gain outside the bandwith of this low pass filter less than -50dB?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, active-filter, passive-filter

I want to block all frequencies higher than 12kHz coming from diffrent sources.
The required filter should have the fastest response possible without inducing any ripple and the gain inside the bandwidth should be higher than +20dB and outside it should be less than -50dB.

My question is how should I design it to have the gain outside less than -50dB.

I'm new to non linear electronics so I don't have much experience.

I know exactly the steps to do for a Sallen Key design but it's just that this outside gain that is confusing me. Does this mean that I should use a 3rd order low pass filter with a Chebyshev 3dB type?
Because if a 1st order LPF gives an amplitude of -20dB/decade this means that I need a 3rd order LPF.

Comment: 1. Why is this tagged [tag:non-linear]? That sounds like the opposite of what you want!

Comment: I suggest that you do some studying on how to **specify a filter**. For example, "gain ... outside it should be less than -50dB". That's not a proper specification. A first order 1 kHz lowpass filter will not have more than 50 dB rejection at 1.1 kHz. So specify **at what frequency** (or relative frequency like 10 x \$f_c\$) you need 50 dB rejection (actually 70 dB rejection as you want a +20 dB in the passband). If you don't study how to do this then you will get in **a mess**.

Comment: You cannot expect 70dB attenuation immediately outside the passband. That would be what is called a "brick wall" filter which is physically unrealisable. You need to define the centre frequency, the width of the passband AND the (larger) width of the stopband. e.g. 1 kHz passband (each side of the centre frequency, total width 2 kHz), 10 kHz stopband. Then use standard filter design techniques (or online calcs) to design a filter meeting that spec. The calc will tell you the required filter order.

Comment: 2. 70 dB difference between pass and stop band isn't impossible (with a non-zero transition width between the two), but it's challenging, and it requires you to take into account phenomena that are different for different frequencies. So, the answer to this depends *very* much on whether this is for 1 to 1.5 Hz, or 100 to 150 kHz, or 100 to 150 MHz, or 4 to 6 GHz. Specify your filter!

Comment: A little more detail : a 3rd order would give you 60dB/decade, so for a centre frequency at 1 MHz and a narrow passband you could only expect your desired attenuation below 30kHz and above 30 MHz.

Comment: It is kind of my fault, I forgot to say that I want to block all frequencies higher than 12kHz

Comment: @P_M great, you have defined the beginning of your stop band! Now you need to define the end of your pass band, too, and that needs to be < than 12 kHz! The closer you put the pass band to the stop band, the harder things become, so be very considerate about what the highest frequency that you actually need to pass is.

Comment: @P_M also, see my first comment: nothing about this is non-linear, so I'm confused why this is even a topic here?

Comment: @P_M though adding info to your question is appreciated, it's inanswerable until you specify the end of your passband. That's the one thing you need to do!

Comment: It's perfectly possible to meet your -70dB stopband requirement at 12 kHz with a first order filter, if your passband bandwidth requirement is DC to 4 Hz. If you want a wider passband than this, then the filter will need to be higher order. 'The fastest response possible' means a Bessel filter, or at least a linear phase passband, which tends to have a poor rate of rolloff into the stopband. You therefore need some stopband zeroes to beef up your stopband attenuation. These filters are tabulated as 'equiripple linear phase with stopband zeros', but you still must specify the passband.

Comment: The passband should be from 0 to 12kHz tgis is why I'm using a lowpass filter

Comment: Passband to 12 kHz, stopband from 12 kHz, is physically unrealisable. Think again.

Comment: If you used a 0.2dB ripple 9th order elliptic, you could get a 10.39 kHz passband, with a stopband 70dB down at 12 kHz, but the delay would be significant, and the group delay variation across the passband horrendous. However, a 9th order filter would be difficult to realise. You'd need very high Q, and any mistuning would wreck passband, stopband, or both. You need to think carefully about what your requirements really are.

Comment: You can approach the performance you want with a digital filter, but you'd have to wait several times the reciprocal of the transition band width to do it. If you wanted a passband to 11999 Hz and stopband from 12000 Hz, you'd need to wait many seconds to accumulate the input data, and that's before you do any processing or output. If it's theoretical, then you can accommodate acausal, and simply use an FFT (with appropriate windowing/filter design) to chop up your spectrum.

Comment: Okay wait, so I'll need the stopband to be at 12kHz and the pass band starting from 0, and regarding the outside of the passband I'll need the transition band to have an amplitude of -50dB. This decribes pretty much what is needed and as I have been told the bessel filter would be better.

Comment: @P_M sorry, this still doesn't tell us how wide the frequency range between the highest frequency that you need to pass and the lowest frequency that you need to stop is. A filter that goes from perfect passing to perfect stopping really is both physically as well as mathematically completely impossible. You need to really think about this aspect of your spec – we can't help you implement something that is impossible. What you call the transition band is actually the stop band.

Answer (score 2):

This is a lowpass filter frequency response specification template. Draw a frequency response keeping within the outline. For most reasonable values of the parameters, you can make a successful filter design in either analogue components or with digital processing. They are certain inviolable constraints which limit how steep a filter can be, together with its delay and ripple. A steep filter means a high delay, they can't both be specified arbitrarily.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhx9xv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The filter 'difficulty' increases roughly as \$\frac{stopband dB}{transition band width}\$

A transition band 30% of the passband width is easy. A transition band 10% of the passband width is getting very difficult.